# Find the lowest natural root

Tags: diophantine-equations

I wanna know, for the equation below, how to:

- Prove if there is always a natural root $x$ that makes $y$ natural
- Get the lowest natural $x$ that makes $y$ natural

$$
x^2+8x-y^2=4n-16\quad\forall
n\in\mathbb N
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the equation can be rewritten as
$$(x+4)^2 - y^2 = 4n \implies (x+y+4)(x-y+4) = 4n =2n \times 2$$
Hence, one solution is
\begin{align}
x+y+4 & = 2n\\
x-y+4 & = 2
\end{align}
Hence,
$$2x+8 = 2n+2 \implies x = n-3$$
$$2y = 2n-2 \implies y = n-1$$
Hence, $(n-3,n-1)$ is always a solution for a given $n$.